# Retrieving the number of integers from a variable

Tags: python

I have a variable x and is used four times throughout my code. I want to find the amount of numbers in the variable and then count up to the highest number starting from 1. Each time, the variable x has different numbers and different amounts of numbers.

```
Guanine = {"C": [(6.958, -5.037, 2.040), (7.355, -4.850, 3.500), 
                 (6.601, -5.985, 4.170), (6.713, -7.099, 3.130),
                 (5.627, -8.157, 3.190), (4.259, -1.254, 0.410),
                 (4.530, -2.553, 0.900), (4.456, -4.566, 1.600),
                 (5.830, -2.919, 1.170), (6.712, -0.955, 0.570)]}
```

x is the first coordinate so (6.958 - 6.712)

Comment: Where's your code? You mentioned it but didn't post it.

Comment: You need be a little more clear. Is `x` an array? If so is all you want the size of that array?

Comment: I still can't see how the new code relates to your text. Could you explain it?

Comment: So for each value I want to basically count up if i have 30 values i want it to count 1.....30, if 35 1....35, however, the amount of numbers in the x variable varie.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this should accomplish what you want:

```
x = [x for x, y, z in Guanine['C']]
```

This returns the list of all `x` values in your data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
length = 0
for i in Guanine["C"]:
    length += len(i)

for i in range(1, length):
    print i  # <-python 2.7 for 3.0 or above use: print(i)
```

This will count the actual numbers in Guanine and count from 1 to that number. Replace 'print i' with any code you want to.